# How to judge whether the database needs to upgrade in Android?

Tags: java, android, database

I'm a new hand,and I want to know how to judge whether the database on app needs to update.Is it to compare the version of server with the version of database on app or anything else?Hope someone could help me.Show me the method or the specific code!Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can judge the database version in the `onUpgrade`